# jquery code does not work in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have this code in jquery to hide a div inside another when a button is clicked, it works in firefox and chrome but not in IE9:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#esconde, #Div1, #Div2").hide();
        $("#act2").click(function () {
            $("#esconde").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1"));
            $("#listadefault").remove().fadeOut(500);

            $("#act3").click(function () {
                $("#listadefault").remove();
                $("#Div1").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1"));

                $("#act4").click(function () {
                    $("#Div2").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1"));
                    $("#listadefault").remove().fadeOut(500);
                });

            });
        });
```

and this is the html:

```
<div id="Div1" class="span12">
    <table class="well table table-condensed">
        <label>tabela 3</label>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Opção 1</th>
                        <th>Opção 2</th>
                        <th>Opção 3</th>
                    </tr>    

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>Dado 1</td><td>Dado 2</td><td>
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                dado1</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>Dado 1</td><td>Dado 2</td><td><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                dado1</button>
                        </div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Dado 1</td><td>Dado 2</td><td><input type="button" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" class="btn btn-primary" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Dado 1</td><td>Dado 2</td><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
                </tbody>


            </table>
    </div>
```

this div above should appear in a #lista1 div.

Comment: Do you get any errors? check the console

Comment: Can you provide a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

you are nisting all the click events inside each other:

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#esconde, #Div1, #Div2").hide();
        $("#act2").click(function () {
            $("#esconde").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1"));
            $("#listadefault").remove().fadeOut(500);
        });

            $("#act3").click(function () {
                $("#listadefault").remove();
                $("#Div1").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1"));
            });
                $("#act4").click(function () {
                    $("#Div2").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1"));
                    $("#listadefault").remove().fadeOut(500);
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not related to your question in any way, but after looking at your javascript I can't fail to notice that you are performing some actions on elements that don't make a whole lot of sense. My comments are inline:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#esconde, #Div1, #Div2").hide();
        $("#act2").click(function () {
            $("#esconde").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1"));
            $("#listadefault").remove().fadeOut(500); // Fading out an element which is already removed

            // Attaching an event handler after a click event is handled.
            // This actually repeats every time you click and even if it's intentional you should perform .one() instead of click, so you don't bind multiple times
            $("#act3").click(function () {
                $("#listadefault").remove();
                $("#Div1").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1")); // Showing an element which is shows. FadeIn shows the element.

                $("#act4").click(function () {
                    $("#Div2").fadeIn(1000).show().append($("#lista1")); // Same thing with fadeIn and show as the above comment.
                    $("#listadefault").remove().fadeOut(500); // Same thing with remove and fadeOut
                });

            });
        });
```

Comment: thanx Konstantin Dinev and AboQutiesh, i forgot to mention that im new to jquery and dont have a lot of xperience. it works now, but i have another question Im nesting all those events so they work from top to bottom, after using them if i try to do it backwords it doesnt works anymore, any tips???